# Using an Access Web App to export all Sharepoint 365 Online User Profiles

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, user-profile

I have built an Access 2013 Web App on Sharepoint 365 Online. The App uses the user's Sharepoint log in email to validate the user's rights and to limit access to data. For this to work, I need to retrieve new Sharepoint User Profile data on a regular basis and add it to the Web App's backend database.

I'm an experienced Access developer(mostly VBA), but new to Sharepoint. Unfortunately, my java and other web skills are also limited.

Is it possible to create an Access Sharepoint Web App that can export the Sharepoint User Profile data to a file? I will appreciate any help and direction that you can offer!

Comment: In my experience the options to do ANYTHING outside of the Access app, like Read external data, is limited. (Like non-existent) If I were to try, I'd look at using REST against the User Profile Service.

Answer (score 0):

Each Access 2013 Web App you create on Office 365 provisions an Azure SQL Server database. You could use SQL Server Management Studio, an Access 2013 desktop client, or anything else you're comfortable with to create a connection to the server and database. You could even create a separate database on your local machine and link that to the auto-hosted app database on Azure.

The connection parameters for the app's database are located in the Backstage area of your Web app.